# binary vector generation (by hamming distance) limit?

Tags: probability, vectors, binary, noise

I have the following problem :

I generate n-bits long binaries (0|1), where every bit is 0 OR 1 with probability 50%.
So, say I generate 'm' such binaries.

The question is what is the probability when generating the next one that it will be  still ~50% away (by hamming distance) from all the generated vectors i.e. almost orthogonal.

OR

said differently, how many binaries I can generate before I generate one that is closer than ~50% away.

Normally if 'n' is big it is almost guaranteed the binary vector is orthogonal to all previously generated. 
I want to find the threshold 'm' of number of vectors I can safely generate for defined 'n'.

I have hard time coming up with formulation on solution to the problem.
So even if you don't have a solution, but just idea on how to mathematically formulate the problem,
please comment out.

---

I was thinking along the lines of single bit logical operations (match i.e. XOR) extended somehow over multiple n-bits.
Then probabilistically treating m-count of vectors in pairs... via at-least one match ..

Comment: I'd start by going at it numerically (which isn't difficult at all for this, even for arbitrary n and m), then see what kind of patterns emerge, and then try to construct a model for this. Then again, I'm a physicist, not a mathematician.

Comment: thats what i'm doing ... programing it... but i want to get definite answer

Comment: Do you have any mathematical model yet, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $N$ uniform random $k$-bit numbers, between $0$ and $2^k-1$, inclusive, the probability of at least two of them being the same is
$$P(n, k) = 1 - \frac{n! {2^k \choose n}}{2^{k n}} = 1 - \frac{(2^k)!}{(2^k - n)! 2^{k n}} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
because this is essentially the well-known [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) but with $2^k$ "days". You are looking for the smallest $n$ where $P(n, k) \ge 0.5$.

Some tabulated values of smallest $n$ that fulfills $P(n, k) \ge 0.5$:
$$\begin{array}{l|r} k & n \\ \hline
4 & 5 \\
8 & 20 \\
12 & 76 \\
16 & 302 \\
20 & 1206 \\
24 & 4823 \\
28 & 19291 \\
32 & 77164 \\
\end{array}$$
To calculate $P(n, k)$ for larger values of $k$, you'll need to approximate $\eqref{NA1}$ somehow, perhaps starting with $P(n, k) = 0.5$ or $2 P(n, k) - 1 = 0$.

---

It turns out there is a very simple approximation:
$$P(n, k) = 1 - e^\frac{-n(n-1)}{2^{k+1}}$$
I encountered it [here](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/).

At the limit $P(n, k) = 0.5$, with large enough $k$, say $k \ge 16$, we can approximate
$$n \approx 0.833 \times 2^\frac{k+1}{2}$$

Comment: thanks, but something looks off because I get approx match (i.e. less than 42% away) around ~500 generated items with 100bit binary vectors !

Comment: @user1019129: So? You could be using a poor PRNG, like the standard C `rand()`, which is a pretty poor LCG; if you used that, your numbers will not be uniformly random. Also, $P(n,k)$ is a *probability*, not any kind of quarantee.